# feed import module: is it possible to have a feed importer without unique field

Tags: feeds, commerce, importing-exporting

I'm using Commerce Kickstart 2.

The SKU field of my products is automatically generated in relation with a serial field that I've created (Serial field module). That was done with the appropriate token generated with the serial field attached to automatic SKU generation. So I want to import my products with Feed Import module without to have a unique field configured, because the SKU will be automatically generated.

Is it possible to setup a feed importer without unique field?

Sorry about my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Feed Tamper module. It allows you to modify the imported data before it is saved. For example, you can specify a token as the default value for the field or add a placeholder which then you can replace when you generate SKU.

Comment: There is the Rewrite plugin. With it you can substitute the sku field with another field that you are importing. But in my case I don't know if I can achieve what I want because I have to take the same SKU value for Product Importer and Product Reference Importer. So even if I could substitute SKU with the token that are used to genereate SKU ([commerce-product:field_book_code]) I think I wouldn't get the same SKU generated in second half of import process, the Product Reference import. I couldn't find placeholder as a plugin options for Tamper. Can you explain better?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when I mentioned placeholder I thought you have your own module that generates SKU so I thought you can populate the field by replacing the placeholder. 

Have you checked Commerce Feeds Module? It seems to do exactly what you want. It can link the products feed to product reference feed. Let me know if I'm missing something.